# How to interpret Parse REST API without --data-url-encode?

Tags: json, curl, parse-platform

For Prase REST API, we can have

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: Y6i5v9PQOAAGlnKnULJJu5odT72ffSCpOnqqPhx9" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: T6STkwY6XqVMySTbqeSZfmli3naZZK9KoxnAcEhR" \
  -G \
  --data-url-encode 'where={"username":"someUser"}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/users
```

Now I'm trying to send the request without `--data-url-encode`, but to append the related query into the URL `https://api.parse.com/1/users`, what shall I do?

I tried

```
curl -X GET \
      -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: Y6i5v9PQOAAGlnKnULJJu5odT72ffSCpOnqqPhx9" \
      -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: T6STkwY6XqVMySTbqeSZfmli3naZZK9KoxnAcEhR" \
      -G \
      https://api.parse.com/1/users?where={"username":"someUser"}
```

but it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First encode `where={"username":"someUser"}` to `where%3D%7B%22username%22%3A%22someUser%22%7D`, then

```
curl -X GET \
      -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: Y6i5v9PQOAAGlnKnULJJu5odT72ffSCpOnqqPhx9" \
      -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: T6STkwY6XqVMySTbqeSZfmli3naZZK9KoxnAcEhR" \
      -G \
      https://api.parse.com/1/users?where%3D%7B%22username%22%3A%22someUser%22%7D
```

works